# Giving current timestamp as folder name in java

Tags: java, directory

As we can give the current time as file name in java , can we do the same with folders too?
Can we give the name of the folder as current time stamp?
please help.Thank You.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes something like this.

```
Date now = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh mm ss");
String time = dateFormat.format(now);
File dir = new File(time);
dir.mkdir();
```

Comment: Thank You all.Learned new things.Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

## Joda-Time

Similar to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27399636/642706) by [James Fox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3565225/james-fox), I suggest using Joda-Time 2.6 (or java.time) for all your date-time work in Java.

## ISO 8601

I would suggest using the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, `2014-12-10T17:05:33Z`. The alphabetical sort happens to also be chronologically sorted. Another benefit is unambiguous reading across nearly all cultures.

## Replace Colons

Except replace COLON for compatibility with the Mac’s [HFS+ file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus). I’ve seen them replaced with HYPHEN `-` or FULL STOP `.` (period).

The resulting value `2014-12-10T17-05-33Z` is compatible with every common OS I know of, other than MS-DOS (too many characters for [8.3 naming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename)).

Do not replace with SOLIDUS (slash) nor REVERSE SOLIDUS (backslash), for compatibility with Unix-style OSes and Microsoft Windows OSes.

For more info, read this article by Apple, [OS X: Cross-platform filename best practices and conventions](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202808).

## Time Zone

Better to specify your desired time zone rather than implicitly relying on the JVM’s current default time zone.

### UTC

If mixing and matching files across computers, you may want to stick with [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) as the time zone.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.UTC );
String output = now.toString().replace( ":" , "-" ); // Replace colons for compatibility with the Mac HFS+ file system.
File f = new File( output );
f.mkdir();
```

Output:

```
output : 2014-12-10T22-35-28.460Z
```

### Default Time Zone

If you want to use the user’s JVM’s current default time zone.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.getDefault() );
…
```

```
output : 2014-12-10T14-49-00.752-08-00
```

### Specific Time Zone

Perhaps you want a specific time zone, such as that of the company’s headquarters.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

## To The Minute Or Second

You may want to drop the fractional second to use a whole second or whole minute. Joda-Time has built-in formatters, [`dateHourMinuteSecond()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateHourMinuteSecond--) or [`dateHourMinute()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateHourMinute--). Those formats omit the `Z` or time zone offset. I suggest appending for clarity; notice the `+"Z"` below.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateHourMinuteSecond();  // Or dateHourMinute();
String output = formatter.print( now ).replace( ":" , "-" )+"Z"; // Replace colons for compatibility with the Mac HFS+ file system.
File f = new File( output );
f.mkdir();
```

When run:

```
output : 2014-12-10T23-07-11Z
```

## Without Punctuation

Another alternative is using no punctuation characters, such as `20141211T214342Z`.

Such formats is even considered standard by ISO 8601, with the formats using  a minimal number of separators officially called “basic”.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.basicDateTimeNoMillis();
String output = formatter.print( now );
File f = new File( output );
f.mkdir();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JodaTime then it can be done this way:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.now();
File f = new File("C:\\tmp\\"+ date.getMillis());
f.mkdir();
```

You get a folder called `1418210024492` (based on the time I ran it).

If you want the timestamp as a date then you can do:

`File f = new File("C:\\tmp\\" + date);`

The date can also be formatted how you wish, like below:

```
String dateTime = new DateTime().toString("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss");
File f = new File("C:\\tmp\\" + dateTime);
f.mkdir();
```

I prefer to use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) as it is a much easier implementation of Date and Time.

Answer (score 0):

```
            Date date =new Date();
            String s=""+date.getTime();
            File file = new File("rootpath"+s);
            file.mkdir();
```